# Dynamically chain Specification using where & and operators

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-data-jpa, specifications

I'm looking for a way to make a global Specification for my repository in order to do something like this :

```
return applicantRepository.findAll(globalSpecificationApplicant, pageRequest);
```

In fact, I got a Specification array and I want to loop into to build the repository global specification with where & and operators (all the specifications are expected in my request).

This is my Service :

```
 public Page<Applicant> findWithParams(RechercheApplicantForm form, PageRequest pageRequest) {

    if(form.isEmptyForm()) {
        logger.debug("empty form findAll");
        return findAll(pageRequest);
    }
    else {
        logger.debug("form ok fnidAllLikeForm");

        List<Specification<Applicant>> lSpecificationApplicant = applicantRepository.getAllSpecificationsLikeForm(form);
        Specification<Applicant> globalSpecificationApplicant = null;
        if (lSpecificationApplicant != null){

            globalSpecificationApplicant = where(lSpecificationApplicant.get(0));

            for (int i = 1; i < lSpecificationApplicant.size(); i++){

                // Doesnt work : "and" not defined
                globalSpecificationApplicant = globalSpecificationApplicant.and(lSpecificationApplicant.get(i));
            }
        }

        return applicantRepository.findAll(globalSpecificationApplicant, pageRequest);

    }

}
```

I can use where clause for the first Specification but I'm not enable to do the same with and clause after..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Specifications.where()` returns an instance of `Specifications` (which is a subtype of `Specification`), you need to declare `globalSpecificationApplicant`accordingly to use it's instance methods:

```
Specifications<Applicant> globalSpecificationApplicant = null;
...
globalSpecificationApplicant = globalSpecificationApplicant.and(lSpecificationApplicant.get(i));
```

Comment: Did you test this ? Because I didnt post my try on it but this doesnt work, the "and" operator only seems to work directly chained to the "where" clause.. Its why I post..

Comment: Pay attention on the definition of `globalSpecificationApplicant` - it's `Specifications`, not `Specification`.

Comment: Sorry I didnt see this.. Thank you!

Comment: Its deprecated now